# When making SNMPv3 connection, is it necessary to specify "Context Name"

Tags: snmp

When we make a SNMPv3 connection, following are the parameters mainly.

- SNMPV3UserName
- SNMPV3ContextName
- SNMPV3SecurityLevel
- SNMPV3AuthProtocol
- SNMPV3AuthPassword
- SNMPV3PrivacyControl
- SNMPV3PrivacyPassword

I want to understand, if is it necessary to specify "SNMPV3ContextName" when connecting. I SNMP RFC Doc and other links I did not find any clear mention.
I have one application which asks for context name if not input by user. I doubt that it should not ask for Context name input as it seems like optional parameter.
RFC I reffered : https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5343

Comment: Net-SNMP is the actual reference design, so play with it and see.

Comment: Seems like you've answered your own question? "The RFC says it's optional, but some managers treat it as mandatory anyway." What else can we say!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes, Although RFC does not have specific mention like MUST or Optional, But I checked on printer panel. There it is allowing value as empty. So I assumed now it as optional. Also additional thing is this field was added later, earlier it was not present. therefore, for backward compatibility etc. it has to be optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***tl;dr: Probably not.***

RFC 5343 says:

> The contextName is a character string (following the SnmpAdminString textual convention of the SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB [RFC3411])

and RFC 3411 defines `SnmpAdminString` as an `OCTET STRING (SIZE (0..255))`.

So, it can be empty. I can't find anything to constrain this more, so an empty string is permitted. Per these RFCs (and also RFC 3412) it seems to be a way to add multiple contexts on top of the `contextEngineID`, *if* your engine needs this disambiguating functionality (to treat it as multiple engines, in a sense).

However, as with anything SNMP, some implementations may impose their own constraints, or just flat-out not follow the spec properly. So you should consult the documentation for the technology that you're using.